# Выпадающий список php с временем

Tags: php

Помогите сделать в форме выпадающий список с временем шагом 30 мин, например 8:00, 8:30, 9:00 и так до 24 часов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<form>

  <label for="add-time">Современный вариант: </label>
  <input id="add-time" type="time" min="09:00" max="18:00" value="13:00" step="1800" pattern="[0-9]{2}:[03]{2}">
</form>
```

В данном случае мы можем задать начало и конец временного периода, шаг  в секундах.

`pattern="[0-9]{2}:[03]{2}"` - запрет на ввод буквенных символов.

Ссылка на документацию:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Круто, не знал о таком...

Comment: паттерн весьма общий какой-то, для минут надо только `[03]0` а не `[0-9]{2}`